# Spark-Salesforce: How to specify server address in spark-salesforce-connector?

Tags: java, apache-spark, salesforce

I need to create Spark's `Dataset<Row>` from Salesforce table.
I have a code snippet I have written to do the same:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import com.springml.spark.salesforce.*;

public class SaleforceReader {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("=========================Salesforce Ingest Begins=========================");
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate();

        Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().format("com.springml.spark.salesforce")
                    .option("username", "someusername")
                    .option("password", "somepassword")
                    .option("soql", "select id, name from mytable")
                    .option("version", "37.0")
                    .load();

        df.show(false);

        spark.close();
        System.out.println("=========================Salesforce Ingest ENDS=========================");
    }

}
```

The above snippet is given in many tutorials and portals.
But this code doesn't specify any Salesforce server to connect to.
Please tell me how to specify the Saleforce server address for this `com.springml.spark.salesforce` Connector.
Do we have something like `.option("login", "//some.salesforce.server.com:port")` ?

Dependency I used:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.springml</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-salesforce_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the question `.option("login", "//some.salesforce.server.com:port")` worked.
Below is the code:

```
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("=========================Salesforce Ingest Begins=========================");
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate();

        Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().format("com.springml.spark.salesforce")
                    .option("username", "someuser@someDomain")
                    .option("password", "mypasswordMYSECURITYTOKEN")
                    .option("login", "https://login.salesforce.com/login/page")
                    .option("soql", "SELECT id from myTable")
                    .option("version", "37.0")
                    .load();

        df.show(false);

        spark.close();
        System.out.println("=========================Salesforce Ingest ENDS=========================");
    }
```